# Beginner doing Visual Basic Project

Tags: vb.net, click

I'm doing a little project with vb.net and I'm having trouble returning the heating cost to a non floating point.

- Call a function to calculate whether the pool is small, medium or large. 
  Use  an  appropriate  branching  structure  in  the  function,  and  return  a  String 
  stating  the  pool’s  category.  The  event  handler  will  assign  this  String  to  the 
  Category label’s Text property. Now with this one here, I have a label called lblCategory.
- Finally, insert a loop structure into the event handler to calculate  the dollar-permonth  value  of  heating. Need a loop to vary temperature variable (which will need to be a floating point type) from the values of 5 to 23 in 
  steps of 1.5.

  Inside this loop, add the temperature variable’s value to the  Avg  Temp  text box 
  and add a corresponding value 
  to the $ Per Month text box, calling a function which uses the following formula:

  Heating Cost = (25 – temperature) * Volume / 32500

  This  will  calculate  the  cost  of  heating  the  pool  to  25  degrees,  by  multiplying  the 
  temperature difference by the pool’s volume, and adjusting by a predetermined value.
  Be  sure  the  function  returns  a  non-floating  point  data  type,  so  as  to  remove  any 
  floating point values from the result.

This is my code so far...

```
Public Class Form1

Const MinLength As Integer = 5
Const MaxLength As Integer = 50
Const MinWidth As Integer = 2
Const MaxWidth As Integer = 20
Const MinDepth As Integer = 2
Const MaxDepth As Integer = 4


Private Function ValidLength(ByVal TestLength As String) As Boolean
    'Length of the pool
    Dim i As Double
    Dim Message As String = ""
    If Double.TryParse(TestLength, i) Then
        If i >= MinLength AndAlso i <= MaxLength Then
            Return True
        End If
    End If
    Message = "Length measurement is not valid." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please enter a value between 5 and 50"
    MessageBox.Show(Message, "Data Invalid", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    Return False
    End
End Function

Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Dim Volume As Double
    Dim Temp As Double
    Dim SA As Double
    Dim HeatingCostInt As Integer
    If Not ValidLength(txtLength.Text) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Not ValidWidth(txtWidth.Text) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Not ValidDepth(txtAvgDepth.Text) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'SurfaceArea Function
    SA = Val(SurfaceArea(txtLength.Text, txtWidth.Text))
    txtSurfaceArea.Text = SA
    'Volume Function
    Volume = Val(Vol(txtLength.Text, txtWidth.Text, txtAvgDepth.Text * 1000))
    txtVolume.Text = Volume
    If PoolVolume(Volume) Then
    End If
    'Temperature Function
    For Temp = 5 To 23 Step 1.5
        txtTableAvgTemp.AppendText(Temp & Environment.NewLine)
        HeatingCost(Temp, Volume)
    Next
End Sub

Private Function ValidWidth(ByVal TestWidth As String) As Boolean
    'Width of the Pool
    Dim Message As String = ""
    Dim i As Double
    If Double.TryParse(TestWidth, i) Then
        If i >= MinWidth And i <= MaxWidth Then
            Return True
        End If
    End If
    Message = "Width measurement is not valid." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please enter a value between 2 and 20"
    MessageBox.Show(Message, "Data Invalid", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    Return False
    End
End Function

Private Function ValidDepth(ByVal TestDepth As String) As Boolean
    'Depth of the pool
    Dim Message As String = ""
    Dim i As Double
    If Double.TryParse(TestDepth, i) Then
        If i >= MinDepth And i <= MaxDepth Then
            Return True
        End If
    End If
    Message = "Depth measurement is not valid." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please enter a value between 2 and 4"
    MessageBox.Show(Message, "Data Invalid", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    Return False
    End
End Function

Private Function SurfaceArea(ByVal Value1 As Double, ByVal Value2 As Double) As Double
    'Calculation for SurfaceArea
    SurfaceArea = Value1 * Value2
    Return SurfaceArea
End Function

Private Function Vol(ByVal Value1 As Double, ByVal Value2 As Double, ByVal Value3 As Double) As Double
    'Calculation for Volume
    Vol = Value1 * Value2 * Value3 * 1000
    Return Vol
End Function

Private Function PoolVolume(ByVal Value1 As Double) As Boolean
    'Pool Volume size that isn't working correctly and I don't know why
    If (Value1 <= 500000) Then
        lblCategory.Text = "Pool Category: Small"
    ElseIf (Value1 > 500000 <= 1500000) Then
        lblCategory.Text = "Pool Category: Medium"
    Else
        lblCategory.Text = "Pool Category: Large"
        Value1 = lblCategory.Text
    End If
    Return PoolVolume
End Function

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    'Ends the program
    End
End Sub

Private Sub txtSurfaceArea_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtSurfaceArea.TextChanged
    'Changes text of SurfaceArea
    txtSurfaceArea.Text = txtLength.Text * txtWidth.Text
End Sub

Private Sub txtVolume_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtVolume.TextChanged
    'Changes text of Volume
    txtVolume.Text = txtLength.Text * txtWidth.Text * txtAvgDepth.Text * 1000
End Sub

Private Function HeatingCost(ByVal Value1 As Double, ByVal Value2 As Double) As Double
    'Calculation for Heating Cost that isn't returning as a non-floating point. Main issue right here!!! 
    Dim Value3 As Double = 32500
    HeatingCost = (25 - Value1) * Value2 / Value3
    txtTableDollars.AppendText(HeatingCost & Environment.NewLine)
End Function

End Class
```

Any help provided would be very nice and helpful for me to finish this thing, thanks for having a look through and taking the time to go through it

Comment: "trouble to get the click event working" isnt the best problem description one could choose. An exception occurs? Output is not what you expect? If so, what is your input and what output do you get. etc. Please update your question to make it easier for others to see, what exactly your problem is.

Comment: I changed the question, it says that I need to return a floating type point to a non-floating type point

Answer (score 0):

You have one Exit Sub to much in your code. After your three condition blocks stands an Exit Sub which will always exit your sub on this line.

```
If Not ValidLength(txtLength.Text) Then
    Exit Sub
End If
If Not ValidWidth(txtWidth.Text) Then
    Exit Sub
End If
If Not ValidDepth(txtAvgDepth.Text) Then
    Exit Sub
End If
Exit Sub
```

Remove this last "Exit Sub" ^^

Comment: Ahh wow, so simple. Didn't even notice that haha, thanks for that :)

Comment: you could have found this very easily by stepping through your code

Answer (score 0):

Your ValidXXX() functions need some work.  If the user types "ChokeOnThis" into the TextBox, for example, the program will crash and burn.  This is because you are passing a String where a Single is expected.  This results in an implicit (automatic) conversion from String to Single.  If the String is not a valid Single (like the "ChokeOnThis" example) then an exception is thrown and the program crashes.

The proper way to do this would be to receive a String into the ValidXXX() functions and then internally use the Integer.TryParse() function like this.  Again, note that the parameter "TestLength" to the function is a String:

```
Private Function ValidLength(ByVal TestLength As String) As Boolean
    'Length of the pool
    Dim i As Single
    If Single.TryParse(TestLength, i) Then
        If i >= MinLength AndAlso i <= MaxLength Then
            Return True
        End If
    End If

    Dim Message As String = _
        "Length measurement is not valid." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "Please enter a value between 5 and 50"
    MessageBox.Show(Message, "Data Invalid", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    Return False
End Function
```

You'd make similar changes to the other ValidXXX() functions.

The same problem exists for your SurfaceArea() and other calculation functions, as they expect Integer parameters but you're passing them String values.  Since the Strings will have been validated at that point, though, the program won't crash.  It's just a bad design to have those conversions happening multiple times.  A better design would validate the inputs and have the converted Integer values stored in local variables so they can be passed to the calculation functions.

Comment: You have a good point but the thing is I need them do be a single function as it's a calculator for pools so there's going to be decimals and what not, I did change my functions to the way you suggested but it just came up with errors when I input decimals and also you wouldn't really be using characters when inputting numbers.

Comment: "you wouldn't really be using characters when inputting numbers"...sure, when they are entered correctly.  Users make typos.  Plus, it's a TextBox, so anything can be entered.  You need to be able to handle that.  If you need decimals then simply change the data type from `Integer` to whatever you need.  I've edited it above to use `Single` instead.

Comment: Okay, I changed that, but I'm stuck with trying to get the floating values to return as non-floating values. The Volume in the HeatingCost function needs to be a floating value but it needs to return the answer to a non-floating

Comment: You can simply convert the number back to an integer with CInt() before displaying it (or returning it): `txtTableDollars.AppendText(CInt(HeatingCost) & Environment.NewLine)`